# I installed xauth and xorg and now my display resolution is reduced

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display

I installed xauth and xorg using the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

After that I rebooted and the following error message appeared on the boot screen and Ubuntu started after a file system check.

```
3.159807] ucsi_cg 1-0008: 12c_transfer failed -110
3.159820j ucsi_ceg 1-0008: ucsI_ccg-init failed = --110
```

Furthermore, the resolution of the display had been reduced, and opening the settings did not restore the resolution to its previous state.

So I uninstalled the two with the following command

```
sudo apt remove xauth
sudo apt remove xorg
```

I uninstalled the two programs with the following commands, but the problem still persisted.
After uninstalling, I tried installing again, but still no change.

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and do not know how to solve this problem.
What is the cause of this situation?

System
CPU: Ryzen7 3800X
GPU: RTX2070 Super
version:Ubuntu22.04.1 LTS Desktop

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop. The command I typed is "apt-get". I typed a hyphen in this question forum and it was automatically converted. Sorry about that. I don't know much about Xorg or Wayland, but I am using the default Ubuntu desktop environment. When I check Settings>about>Windwing System in Ubuntu, it shows X11. Does this mean that I am using Xorg instead of Wayland?
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop.
The command I typed is "apt-get".
I typed a hyphen in this question forum and it was automatically converted. Sorry about that.
I don't know much about Xorg or Wayland, but I am using the default Ubuntu desktop environment.
When I check Settings>about>Windwing System in Ubuntu, it shows X11. Does this mean that I am using Xorg instead of Wayland?

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible that the cause of this problem is something other than the installation of xauth and xorg!
I'll do some more research on my own...

Postscript.
I updated the NVIDEA driver using Software Updator and the problem was solved.